# envoy filter fails to add custom header

Tags: istio

I added EnvoyFilter to the Gateway level that should add custom header to every request, but it fails to do it. Please assist what is wrong. The code is:

```
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: loginservice-app
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: login-gwy
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: GATEWAY
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.filters.http.router"
    patch:
      operation: MERGE
      value:
        name: envoy.filters.http.lua
        typed_config:
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua"
          inlineCode: |
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                request_handle:headers():add("x-custom-header", "yes");
              end
```

I expected EnvoyFilter will add custom header to every request

Comment: Please check following link this can be achieved using virtual service. 
 https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Headers